# Connect to a MySQL Database on the LAN using LUA on ESP8266

Tags: mysql, lua, remote-access, esp8266

I have a MySQL Db on a raspberry pi, IP:192.168.100.230.
I have a NodeMCU (ESP8266) IP:192.168.100.150.
The raspberry pi MySQL has the following database used for development:

```
Database: pythonProg
User: pythonUser
Pass: password123
Table: espTest
```

I am trying to get the ESP8266 to log a temperature (Integer) to the database on the Pi using LUA.

The code I have to test the connection is:

```
-- Script to test the connection to a MySQL Db
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"
local env  = mysql.mysql()
local conn = env:connect('pythonProg','pythonUser'@'192.168.100.230','password123')
print(env,conn)
```

The error is

> MySQL_test1.lua:4: ')' expected near '@'

There is so little information out there on these little devices, any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: that's just a string error. removce the single quotes around the @ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

That connection string should actually be without the extra quotes:

```
env:connect('pythonProg','pythonUser@192.168.100.230','password123')
```

Or, if you really really want to keep the '@' separated ;-) (don't do this)

```
'pythonUser'..'@'..'192.168.100.230'
```